# price pool distribution with a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to make a small program, that gives me price distributions for tournaments and I thought using a series would be good for that.

I found this formula:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} a\ r^{k-1} = \frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$$

Let's say I want the first price to get 50% and want to pay out places 1 through 8,
then I'd have $n = 8$, $a = 1/2$. Is there a formula that would let me find the right r without having to solve for r every time?

Or what would be a better approach?

thank you

Comment: What do you exactly want? It seems to me that you are looking for the $r$ that satisfies $2=1+r+r^2+\dots+r^7$, and you only have to solve it once.

Comment: I'd like to be able to make the program such that I can change n and a

Comment: I would recommend doing it numerically. Even if there is a closed form solution, it will probably be so messy that it's faster to do it numerically from the beginning. A good initial guess would probably be $r=1-a$ (the exact solution in the case $n=\infty$), which is pretty good for $n$ large (like eight). Also, make sure that $a>1/n$ so that $r<1$ and the formula works.